# Storing Google AppEngine cookie in Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, cookies, local-storage

I am developing an Android client with GAE backend and I am using the phone accounts for authentication.

After I retrieve the authentication cookie from GAE, I can make authenticated calls to the server, but as soon as the application is closed, when the app re-launches, I have to run the auth proces again, ask for e new cookie. Is there a way to store that Cookie object and check for it after the first time the auth happens so I don't have to do it every time the app launches?

Comment: Why not just re-authenticate? It won't require prompting the user.

Comment: I wold like to avoid and extra server call if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good use for the SharedPreferences

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences().edit().putString("cookie", myCookie).commit();
String myCookie = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences.getString("cookie", null);
```

Comment: Ok, so this stores the cookie value as a string, which may be sufficient. I was wondering if there was a way to store a loaded instance of the Cookie class.

Comment: same way, just serialize the cookie class and write it to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leverage functionality of the already implemented provider you should use `AccountManager`:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(MyActivity.this);
Account[] aArray = am.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE);
/* choose correct account from the resulting array */
/* ex. Account a = aArray[0]; */
try {
  String token = am.blockingGetAuthToken(a, Constants.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE, false);
} catch (OperationCanceledException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (AuthenticatorException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should override getTokenType() method of your account authenticator to return GAE authentication cookie in the result bundle under the key `AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN`. Refer to [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccountsByType%28java.lang.String%29) class description for detailed authentication procedure.

Comment: My question was more about how to store that cookie that gets set as the auth token comes back from GAE after authentication with the account.